# Increasing java GUI grid size

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to increase the size of my GUI grid from 25x25 to 40x40, I've been trying to locate the GUI grid size in the code and for some reason I was unable to do so i would really appriciate it if anyone could help me understand what needs to be changed to alter the grid size for the GUI.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author MouseTeam
 */
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private int mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

    private JButton startButton; // start button!
    private JButton[][] buttons; // have all the grid buttons

    private JPanel gridPanel;// the panel holding the grid of buttons
    private JPanel[][] mainGrid; // each panel holds a button from button variable matrix of buttons

    private JLabel numberOfLeftFood, numberOfSteps; // labels in the gui
    private ArrayList<Object[]> bestGenerationsAndGrid; // holds all best of each 10 generations

    private JTextField terminalProbability, crossoverProbability, mutationProbability,
            gridWidth, gridHeight, maxDepth, populationSize, numberOfGenerations;

    private JLabel generationNoLabel;

    /**
     * initilizes the primere look of the gui and it's characteristics
     */
    public GUI() {

        int width = Parameters.gridWidth;
        int height = Parameters.gridHeight;

        gridPanel = new JPanel();
        buttons = new JButton[width][height];
        gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(width, height));
        mainGrid = new JPanel[width][height];

        setSize(600, 600);
        setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
        JPanel right = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        startButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        terminalProbability = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        crossoverProbability = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        mutationProbability = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        gridWidth = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        gridHeight = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        maxDepth = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        populationSize = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        numberOfGenerations = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        JLabel jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JLabel jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JLabel jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JLabel jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JLabel jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JLabel jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JLabel jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JLabel jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        generationNoLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        numberOfLeftFood = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        numberOfSteps = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        JPanel center = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        terminalProbability.setText("0.4");

        startButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        startButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 0));
        startButton.setText("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                startButtonAction(evt);
            }
        });

        crossoverProbability.setText("0.8");

        mutationProbability.setText("0.05");

        gridWidth.setText("25");

        gridHeight.setText("25");

        maxDepth.setText("20");

        populationSize.setText("100");

        numberOfGenerations.setText("20");

        jLabel1.setText("Terminal Probability");

        jLabel2.setText("Mutation Probability");

        jLabel3.setText("Crossover Probability");

        jLabel4.setText("Grid Width");

        jLabel5.setText("Grid Height");

        jLabel6.setText("Max Depth");

        jLabel7.setText("Population Size");

        jLabel8.setText("Number Of Generations");

        generationNoLabel.setText("Generation number");
        generationNoLabel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        generationNoLabel.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        generationNoLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

        numberOfLeftFood.setText("Number of left food");
        numberOfLeftFood.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        numberOfLeftFood.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        numberOfLeftFood.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

        numberOfSteps.setText("Number of steps");
        numberOfSteps.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        numberOfSteps.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        numberOfSteps.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout rightLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(right);
        right.setLayout(rightLayout);
        rightLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(rightLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(generationNoLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(startButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(rightLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addGroup(rightLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel1))
                                                        .addGap(5, 5, 5))
                                                .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addComponent(numberOfGenerations, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                                        .addComponent(maxDepth, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                        .addComponent(gridHeight, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                        .addComponent(gridWidth, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                        .addComponent(mutationProbability, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                        .addComponent(terminalProbability, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                .addComponent(crossoverProbability, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(populationSize, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addComponent(numberOfLeftFood, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(numberOfSteps, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addContainerGap())
        );
        rightLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(rightLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                        .addComponent(startButton)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(terminalProbability, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(mutationProbability, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(crossoverProbability, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(gridWidth, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(gridHeight, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel5))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(maxDepth, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel6))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(populationSize, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(rightLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(numberOfGenerations, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel8))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(generationNoLabel)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(numberOfLeftFood)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(numberOfSteps)
                        .addContainerGap(65, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
        initGrid();
        add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);

    }

    /**
     *take cheese coordinates and fill the grid with the cheese
     */
    public void putCheese(ArrayList<Coordinate> cheese) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cheese.size(); ++i) {

            Coordinate coord = cheese.get(i);
            updatDisplay(coord.i, coord.j, "2.png");

        }
    }
    /**
     * Make a button with a resizible images 
     */
    public static JButton makeButton(String path) {
        try {
            BufferedImage master;

            if (path == "") {
                path = "default.png";
            }
            master = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
            JButton btn = new JButton() {

                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(90, 50);
                }

            };
            btn.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    JButton btn = (JButton) e.getComponent();
                    Dimension size = btn.getSize();
                    Insets insets = btn.getInsets();
                    size.width -= insets.left + insets.right;
                    size.height -= insets.top + insets.bottom;
                    if (size.width > size.height) {
                        size.width = -1;
                    } else {
                        size.height = -1;
                    }

                    Image scaled = master.getScaledInstance(size.width, size.height, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                    btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scaled));

                }

            });
            return btn;
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * start mouse move
     */
    public void startMouse() {

        MouseThread mTh = new MouseThread();
        mTh.start();

    }

    /**
     * handle Start button click, with initilize Parameters fields and displaying the grids variables and start it..
     *
     * @param evt
     */
    public void startButtonAction(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        this.generationNoLabel.setText("Please wait..");

        //initilize Parameters fields
        Parameters.terminalProbability = Double.parseDouble(terminalProbability.getText());
        Parameters.crossoverProbability = Double.parseDouble(crossoverProbability.getText());
        Parameters.mutationProbability = Double.parseDouble(mutationProbability.getText());

        if ((Parameters.terminalProbability < 0 || Parameters.terminalProbability > 1)
                || (Parameters.crossoverProbability < 0 || Parameters.crossoverProbability > 1)
                || (Parameters.mutationProbability < 0 || Parameters.mutationProbability > 1)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter probabilities between 0 and 1 inclusive");
            return;
        }

        Parameters.gridWidth = Integer.parseInt(gridWidth.getText());
        Parameters.gridHeight = Integer.parseInt(gridHeight.getText());

        if (Parameters.gridWidth > 25 || Parameters.gridHeight > 25) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Max recommended grid size is 25 * 25!");
            return;
        }

        Parameters.maxDepth = Integer.parseInt(maxDepth.getText());

        Parameters.populationSize = Integer.parseInt(populationSize.getText());
        Parameters.numberOfGenerations = Integer.parseInt(numberOfGenerations.getText());

        startButton.setEnabled(false);

        // initilize main program objects like grid and tournament selection, population etc..
        Grid g = new Grid(Parameters.gridHeight, Parameters.gridWidth, Parameters.cheeseFraction);

        // System.out.println(g.getNumberOfCheeseInGrid());
        TournamentSelection sel = new TournamentSelection(Parameters.crossoverProbability);
        Population p = new Population(Parameters.populationSize, g, sel);

        //now starting evolution
        Evolution e = new Evolution(p, Parameters.numberOfGenerations);
        e.evolve(this);

        //start actual mouse simulation
        startMouse();
//        startButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    /**
     * update cell at x,y with picture that have path
     */
    public void updatDisplay(int x, int y, String path) {

        mainGrid[x][y].removeAll();

        buttons[x][y] = makeButton(path);
        buttons[x][y].setBackground(Color.green);
        mainGrid[x][y].add(buttons[x][y]);
    }

    /**
     * change visited cell to red
     */
    public void updateVisitedButton(int x, int y) {
        mainGrid[x][y].removeAll();
        buttons[x][y].removeComponentListener(null);
        buttons[x][y] = new JButton();
        buttons[x][y].setBackground(Color.red);
        mainGrid[x][y].add(buttons[x][y]);
    }

    /**
     * reinitilize the grid with the given cheese positions
     *
     * @param cheese
     */
    public void initGrid() {
        gridPanel.removeAll();
        int width = Parameters.gridWidth;
        int height = Parameters.gridHeight;

        buttons = new JButton[width][height];
        gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(width, height));
        mainGrid = new JPanel[width][height];

        //make all cells green again and put mouse at position 0 0
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                mainGrid[i][j] = new JPanel();
                mainGrid[i][j].setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
                buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.green);

                mainGrid[i][j].add(buttons[i][j]);
                gridPanel.add(mainGrid[i][j]);
            }
        }
        add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        updatDisplay(0, 0, "right.png");

        validate();
        repaint();
    }

    public void setBestGenerationsAndGrid(ArrayList<Object[]> bestGenerationsAndGrid) {
        this.bestGenerationsAndGrid = bestGenerationsAndGrid;
    }

    /**
     * the class that handles mouse moving on the grid
     */
    class MouseThread extends Thread {

        Coordinate coord;
        boolean waited = false;

        public MouseThread() {

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //start actual mouse simulation

            Object[] temp;

            ArrayList<Coordinate> path, grid;
            int[] fitness;
            for (int j = 0; j < bestGenerationsAndGrid.size(); ++j) {

                //have the best of the ith * 10 path and the correpsonding grid
                temp = bestGenerationsAndGrid.get(j);

                path = (ArrayList<Coordinate>) temp[0];
                fitness = (int[]) temp[1];
                grid = (ArrayList< Coordinate>) temp[2];

                //make all grid green
                initGrid();
                //put cheese on the grid and the mouse
                putCheese(grid);

                generationNoLabel.setText("Best of the first " + ((j + 1) * 10) + " generations");
                numberOfLeftFood.setText("Number of food left: " + fitness[0]);
                numberOfSteps.setText("Number of Steps: " + fitness[1]);

                //start simulation
                for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i) {
                    coord = path.get(i);
                    try {
                        if (!waited) {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                            waited = true;
                        } else {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        }
                        updateVisitedButton(mouseX, mouseY);

                        updatDisplay(coord.i, coord.j, "right.png");

                        validate();
                        repaint();

                        mouseX = coord.i;
                        mouseY = coord.j;

                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
                    }
                }
            }


        }

    }
}
```

rest will be added below not enough room for grid class can anyone pinpoint? how to increase GUI Grid size? 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

GRID CLASS:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * our program is summarize in a mouse looking for cheese on a grid, this class holds everything about the grid and the cheese on it
 * @author MouseTeam
 */
public class Grid {
    private char[][] grid;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private double cheeseFraction;
    private final MersenneTwister rnd;
    private int countCheese;
    private ArrayList<Coordinate> points;


    public Grid(int height, int width, double cheese){
        rnd = Parameters.rnd;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.cheeseFraction = cheese;
        points = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();

        grid = new char[height][width];
        int buff = Parameters.wallBuff;
        countCheese=0;
        for(int i=buff; i<height-buff; i++)
            for(int j=buff; j<width-buff; j++)
                if (rnd.nextDouble()<Parameters.cheeseFraction){
                    grid[i][j] = '*';
                    points.add(new Coordinate(i,j));
                    countCheese++;
                }
                else
                    grid[i][j] = '-';
    }


    public Grid(Grid other){
        rnd = other.rnd;
        this.width = other.width;
        this.height = other.height;
        this.cheeseFraction = other.cheeseFraction;

        grid = new char[height][width];
        countCheese = other.countCheese;
        for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
                grid[i][j] = other.grid[i][j];
    }


    public ArrayList<Coordinate> getCheesePoints(){
        return this.points;
    }

    /**
     * show where are the cheese on the grid
     */
    public void printCheeseCoordinatesOnGrid(){
        System.out.println("Cheese on grid: ");
        for (Coordinate c: points){
            System.out.println(c.i+ "   "+c.j);
        }
    }


    public boolean isCheese(int i, int j){
        return grid[i][j] == '*';
    }


    public void removeCheese(int i, int j){
        if(isCheese(i,j)){
            grid[i][j] = '!';
            countCheese--;
        }
    }

    public int getNumberOfCheeseInGrid(){
        return countCheese;
    }


    public void printGrid(){
        for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
                if (grid[i][j]==0)
                     System.out.print("#");
                else
                     System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    boolean ifCheeseAhead(Info info) {
            int i, j;
            i=info.i;
            j=info.j;

            if (info.direction.equals("right"))
               j = (j+1)%width;


            if(info.direction.equals("left")){
                if(j == 0) j=width-1;
                j = j-1;
            }

            if (info.direction.equals("down"))
                i = (i+1)%height;

            if(info.direction.equals("up")){
                if(i == 0) i=height-1;
                i = i-1;
            }

            return isCheese(i,j);
    }


    boolean ifWallAhead(Info info) {
            int i, j;
            i=info.i;
            j=info.j;

            if (info.direction.equals("right")){
               if(j+3 >=width)
                   return true;
               else
                   return false;
            }

            if(info.direction.equals("left")){
                if(j-3 <0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

            if (info.direction.equals("down")){
               if(i+3 >= height)
                   return true;
               else
                   return false;
            }

            if(info.direction.equals("up")){
                if(i-3 < 0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

            return false;
    }



    boolean ifCheeseConcentrationAhead(Info info) {
        int left=0, right=0, up=0, down=0;
        int i,j;

        for(i=0; i<height; i++){
            for(j=info.j+1; j<width; j++)
                if(isCheese(i,j))
                    right++;

            for(j=0; j<info.j; j++)
                if(isCheese(i,j))
                    left++;
        }

        for(j=0; j<width; j++){
            for(i=0; i<info.i; i++)
                if(isCheese(i,j))
                    up++;

            for(i=info.i+1; i<height; i++)
                if(isCheese(i,j))
                    down++;
        }

        if (info.direction.equals("right"))
            return (right>=left && right>=up && right>=down);


        if(info.direction.equals("left"))
            return (left>=right && left>=up && left>=down);

        if (info.direction.equals("down"))
            return (down>=left && down>=right && down>=up);

        if(info.direction.equals("up"))
            return (up>=left && up>=right && up>=down);

        System.err.println("Error direction 1!");
        System.exit(1);

        return false;
    }




    String ifSmellFrom(Info info) {
        int stepsLeft= Integer.MAX_VALUE, stepsRight=Integer.MAX_VALUE, stepsUp=Integer.MAX_VALUE, stepsDown=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        double wind = windEffect(); //add the dependency upon the wind effect and direction
        for(int right = 1; info.j+right<width; right++){
            for(int up=0; up<=right && info.i-up>=0; up++)
                if (isCheese(info.i-up,info.j+right)){
                    if (right+up < stepsRight)
                        stepsRight = right+up;
                    break;
                }

            for(int down=0; down<=right && info.i+down<height; down++)
                if (isCheese(info.i+down,info.j+right)){
                    if (right+down < stepsRight)
                        stepsRight = right+down;
                    break;
                }
        }

        for(int left = 1; info.j-left>=0; left++){
            for(int up=0; up<=left && info.i-up>=0; up++)
                if (isCheese(info.i-up,info.j-left)){
                    if (left+up < stepsLeft)
                        stepsLeft = left+up;
                    break;
                }

            for(int down=0; down<=left && info.i+down<height; down++)
                if (isCheese(info.i+down,info.j-left)){
                    if (left+down < stepsLeft)
                        stepsLeft = left+down;
                    break;
                }
        }  

        for(int up = 1; info.i-up>=0; up++){
            for(int left=0; left<=up && info.j-left>=0; left++)
                if (isCheese(info.i-up,info.j-left)){
                    if (left+up < stepsUp)
                        stepsUp = left+up;
                    break;
                }

            for(int right=0; right<=up && info.j+right<width; right++)
                if (isCheese(info.i-up,info.j+right)){
                    if (right+up < stepsUp)
                        stepsUp = right+up;
                    break;
                }
        }

        for(int down = 1; info.i+down<height; down++){
            for(int left=0; left<=down && info.j-left>=0; left++)
                if (isCheese(info.i+down,info.j-left)){
                    if (left+down < stepsDown)
                        stepsDown = left+down;
                    break;
                }

            for(int right=0; right<=down && info.j+right<width; right++)
                if (isCheese(info.i+down,info.j+right)){
                    if (right+down < stepsDown)
                        stepsDown = right+down;
                    break;
                }
        }


        if (info.direction.equals("right")){
            if(stepsRight <= stepsLeft && stepsRight <= stepsUp && stepsRight <= stepsDown) {
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "forward";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "left";
                }else{
                    return "right";
                }
            }

            if(stepsLeft <= stepsRight && stepsLeft <= stepsUp && stepsLeft <= stepsDown) {

                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "backward";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "left";
                }else{
                    return "right";
                }               
            }

            if(stepsUp <= stepsLeft && stepsUp <= stepsRight && stepsUp <= stepsDown){
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "left";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "forward";
                }else{
                    return "backward";
                }
            }

            if(stepsDown <= stepsLeft && stepsDown <= stepsRight && stepsDown <= stepsUp){
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "right";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "forward";
                }else{
                    return "backward";
                }
            }
        }


        if(info.direction.equals("left")){
            if(stepsRight <= stepsLeft && stepsRight <= stepsUp && stepsRight <= stepsDown) {

                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "backward";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "left";
                }else{
                    return "right";
                }               
            }

            if(stepsLeft <= stepsRight && stepsLeft <= stepsUp && stepsLeft <= stepsDown){
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "forward";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "left";
                }else{
                    return "right";
                }
            }

            if(stepsUp <= stepsLeft && stepsUp <= stepsRight && stepsUp <= stepsDown){
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "right";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "forward";
                }else{
                    return "backward";
                }
            }

            if(stepsDown <= stepsLeft && stepsDown <= stepsRight && stepsDown <= stepsUp){
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "left";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "forward";
                }else{
                    return "backward";
                }
            }
        }


        if (info.direction.equals("down")){
            if(stepsRight <= stepsLeft && stepsRight <= stepsUp && stepsRight <= stepsDown){
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "left";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "forward";
                }else{
                    return "backward";
                }
            }

            if(stepsLeft <= stepsRight && stepsLeft <= stepsUp && stepsLeft <= stepsDown){
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "right";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "forward";
                }else{
                    return "backward";
                }
            }

            if(stepsUp <= stepsLeft && stepsUp <= stepsRight && stepsUp <= stepsDown) {

                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "backward";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "left";
                }else{
                    return "right";
                }               
            }

            if(stepsDown <= stepsLeft && stepsDown <= stepsRight && stepsDown <= stepsUp){
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "forward";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "left";
                }else{
                    return "right";
                }
            }
        }


        if(info.direction.equals("up")){
            if(stepsRight <= stepsLeft && stepsRight <= stepsUp && stepsRight <= stepsDown){
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "right";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "forward";
                }else{
                    return "backward";
                }
            }

            if(stepsLeft <= stepsRight && stepsLeft <= stepsUp && stepsLeft <= stepsDown){
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "left";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "forward";
                }else{
                    return "backward";
                }
            }

            if(stepsUp <= stepsLeft && stepsUp <= stepsRight && stepsUp <= stepsDown){
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "forward";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "left";
                }else{
                    return "right";
                }
            }

            if(stepsDown <= stepsLeft && stepsDown <= stepsRight && stepsDown <= stepsUp){
                if(wind >= 0d && wind <= 0.8d)
                    return "backward";
                else if(wind > 0.8d && wind <= 0.9d) {
                    return "left";
                }else{
                    return "right";
                }
            }
        }

        System.err.println("Error direction 2!");
        System.exit(1);

        return null;
    }




    boolean ifSmellAhead(Info info) {
        return ifSmellFrom(info).equals("forward");
    }



    void ifCheeseAheadNmoveN(Info info, int N, ArrayList<Coordinate> path) {
        if (info.direction.equals("right"))
            if(info.j+N < width && isCheese(info.i,info.j+N)){   
                info.remainedSteps-=N;
                for(int i=1; i<=N; i++)
                    path.add(new Coordinate(info.i, info.j+i));
                info.j+=N;
            }

        if(info.direction.equals("left"))
            if(info.j-N >= 0 && isCheese(info.i,info.j-N)){
                info.remainedSteps-=N;
                for(int i=1; i<=N; i++)
                    path.add(new Coordinate(info.i, info.j-i));
                info.j-=N;
            }

        if (info.direction.equals("down"))
            if(info.i+N < height && isCheese(info.i+N,info.j)){
                for(int i=1; i<=N; i++)
                    path.add(new Coordinate(info.i+i, info.j));
                info.i+=N;
                info.remainedSteps-=N;
            }

        if(info.direction.equals("up"))
            if(info.i-N >= 0 && isCheese(info.i-N,info.j)){
                for(int i=1; i<=N; i++)
                    path.add(new Coordinate(info.i-i, info.j));
                info.i-=N;
                info.remainedSteps-=N;
            }


        removeCheese(info.i, info.j);

    }

    double windEffect() {   //used to alter the smell function above on the random probability
        boolean effect = rnd.nextBoolean();
        if(effect)
            return rnd.nextDouble();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    boolean ifFearAhead(Info arg0) {    //based upon the definition that is mouse fears of something ahead of him and changes direction
        //it is done on random probability: 
        double fearProb = rnd.nextDouble();
        if (arg0.direction.equals("right")){
           if(fearProb < 1d/4d)
               return true;
           else
               return false;
        }
        if(arg0.direction.equals("left")){
            if(fearProb < 2d/4d)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        if (arg0.direction.equals("down")){
            if(fearProb < 3d/4d)
               return true;
           else
               return false;
        }

        if(arg0.direction.equals("up")){
            if(fearProb < 4d/4d)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        return false;
    }




}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Parameters.gridWidth = Integer.parseInt(gridWidth.getText());
Parameters.gridHeight = Integer.parseInt(gridHeight.getText());
```

uses

```
gridWidth.setText("25");
gridHeight.setText("25");
```

from further up.

That perhaps seems a little backward to me. I'd rather define 2 integer constants and populate both the parameter setup and the text boxes from those.

Comment: what is this an answer or what??

Comment: Yes it is - "I've been trying to locate the GUI grid size in the code and for some reason I was unable to do so". Think I've answered it